# How to correctly migrate to Spring Cloud stream v4?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have some problems rewriting the app to v4 of Spring Cloud stream, more specifically the tests.

This I rewrote successfully:

```
    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void processMessage(String message) {
...
```

to:

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<String> processMessage() {
        return message -> {
        ...
```

In the test, I am auto wiring the `Sink` simply with:

```
    @Autowired
    private Sink sink;
```

and later using it as follows:

```
        sink.input().send(message);
```

However, the `Sink` class is not found anymore. The migration guide is still being written but I need to upgrade now. Can somebody help how I can send message to the Sink in the test?

Answer (score 1):

To test such a scenario, you need to use the test binder based on the in-memory Spring Integration channels. See here for an example: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/main/core/spring-cloud-stream-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/ImplicitFunctionBindingTests.java#L406

There are many other tests that exercise the various functional bindings in that test class. The old `Sink`, `Source` and `Processor` interfaces are now removed from the framework in lieu of the functional binding model.

Comment: `TestChannelBinderConfiguration` does not exist in `spring-cloud-stream-test-support`. Only in binder test lib.

Comment: `InputDestination` as well.

Comment: you need `spring-cloud-stream-test-binder` as well.